# Create 2-dimensional range

Tags: python, python-2.7, numpy, scipy

I have a column vector of start values `X`, and a column vector of end values `Z`, and I want to create a matrix that creates linspaces between `X` and `Z` of size `n`. Is there a way to generate that directly without iterating?

Say `n=10`, and `Z` in this simple example is just a vector of `20`. Then, the following code

```
X = np.arange(0,5,1)

Y = np.empty((5, 10))
for idx in range(0, len(X)):
    Y[idx] = np.linspace(X[idx], 20, 10)
```

generates what I want, but it requires iteration. Is there any more performant solution, or one directly built in without all that do-it-yourself logic?

Here's the expected output for my test case:

```
Y
array([[  0.        ,   2.22222222,   4.44444444,   6.66666667,
          8.88888889,  11.11111111,  13.33333333,  15.55555556,
         17.77777778,  20.        ],
       [  1.        ,   3.11111111,   5.22222222,   7.33333333,
          9.44444444,  11.55555556,  13.66666667,  15.77777778,
         17.88888889,  20.        ],
       [  2.        ,   4.        ,   6.        ,   8.        ,
         10.        ,  12.        ,  14.        ,  16.        ,
         18.        ,  20.        ],
       [  3.        ,   4.88888889,   6.77777778,   8.66666667,
         10.55555556,  12.44444444,  14.33333333,  16.22222222,
         18.11111111,  20.        ],
       [  4.        ,   5.77777778,   7.55555556,   9.33333333,
         11.11111111,  12.88888889,  14.66666667,  16.44444444,
         18.22222222,  20.        ]])
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's what [np.meshgrid](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.meshgrid.html) is for.  Edit: Nevermind, that's not what you wanted.

Here's what you want:

```
>>> X = np.arange(0, 5, 1)[:, None]
>>> Y = np.linspace(0, 1, 10)[None, :]
>>> X+Y*(20-X)
array([[  0.        ,   2.22222222,   4.44444444,   6.66666667,
      8.88888889,  11.11111111,  13.33333333,  15.55555556,
     17.77777778,  20.        ],
   [  1.        ,   3.11111111,   5.22222222,   7.33333333,
      9.44444444,  11.55555556,  13.66666667,  15.77777778,
     17.88888889,  20.        ],
   [  2.        ,   4.        ,   6.        ,   8.        ,
     10.        ,  12.        ,  14.        ,  16.        ,
     18.        ,  20.        ],
   [  3.        ,   4.88888889,   6.77777778,   8.66666667,
     10.55555556,  12.44444444,  14.33333333,  16.22222222,
     18.11111111,  20.        ],
   [  4.        ,   5.77777778,   7.55555556,   9.33333333,
     11.11111111,  12.88888889,  14.66666667,  16.44444444,
     18.22222222,  20.        ]])
```

Answer (score 1):

List comprehensions at least are faster, and sometimes easier to understand than loops (also, almost always use `xrange` instead of `range`, btw):

```
matrix = np.array([np.linspace(x, 20, 10) for x in X])
```

Comment: I see. So even if `20` is not a constant, as long as I can generate it from `x`, I am fine with this method.

Comment: This is going to be a lot slower than a solution using NumPy broadcasting.

Comment: "almost always use `xrange` instead of `range`" This is true for Python2. Python3 `range` is `xrange`.

Comment: @ljetibo: yep, that's true. But since python3 doesn't have xrange AFAIK, OP would have noticed.

Comment: @user2357112: yes, usually that's the case; however, I don't think any use case of OP's question is covered by broadcasting. --- see his "ah,ok if 20 is not a constant" comment.